# Were the Woods an enchanted location?

Tags: plot-explanation, into-the-woods

Were the woods from *Into the Woods* an enchanted location that influenced people who entered it, or events that transpired in it, due to its inherent eldritch properties?

Or was it an ordinary group of trees (in a land where magic and enchantment are real)?

Comment: The baker and his wife live outside the woods, but are still affected by the witch's spell

Comment: "*The woods are just trees - The trees are just wood - No need to be afraid there"*